# ORACLE SQL query to return a value from a row where strings of rows in other tables match

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to get this to work, it should be simple but im having trouble nailing it down. I just need to return the value of num where the strings match in the same table and another one.

table 1

```
string    num
-------   -----
xyzxy       100
```

table 2

```
string     othernum
--------   --------
xyzxy       200


SELECT num FROM table1 WHERE (SELECT string FROM table1 = SELECT string FROM table2)
```

Comment: Add some more sample table data and also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

use `exists()`

```
select num from table1 t1 where exists (select 1 from table2 where string = t1.string)
```

Answer (score 0):

use in(?)：

```
SELECT num 
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE t1.string in (SELECT string FROM table2)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below query:

```
SELECT t1.num FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2 
WHERE t1. string = t2.string;
```